# Replace the image name in img src tag in XSL

Tags: image, xslt, replace, src

I want replace "Test.png" with "string[1]" ...Example "Test.png" => "Fail.png"  ...

How to do that in XSL ?

```
 <xsl:when test="string[1] = 'Fail'">
     <td> <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="Test.png" height="182" width="182"></img></a></td>
 </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
      <td> </td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks ,
Muthu Selvan SR

Answer (score 1):

Use an **[attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**: `src="{string[1]}.png"`

A single attribute specification in a literal result element in the stylesheet can have any number of attribute value templates.  Each is treated as an `<xsl:value-of>`.